# how to preallocate space for a vector of vectors of ints to avoid unnecessary system calls

Tags: c++, operating-system, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

Here's a big but good-enough simplification of a problem I have. Say I have a vector of ints that I want to group into a vector of vector of ints based on some property. E.g. {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} and I want to group this vector into triplets. So:

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10}}

To make this scale, I want to avoid unnecessarily making sys calls for allocations, both for adding ints to the inner vectors (e.g. {1, 2}.push_back(3)) and adding subvectors to the outer vector (e.g. {{1, 2, 3}}.push_back({4, 5, 6})).

I'm guessing I can do this with a custom allocator, but is there a much simpler way to only allocate dynamic memory once?

The usecase of this grouping into vectors ultimately is that I want clients to be able to iterate over the subvectors:

e.g.

```
for (auto subvector : outer_vector) {
    for (auto num : subvector) {
            // do stuff
    }
}
```

So maybe there's an easier way to ultimately solve this without all the allocations?

Comment: A modern os returns a pointer to 1 full page after a memory syscall. The standard library implementation (glibc on Linux) does the management of when to actually request new pages to the kernel. You don't need to manage that. Most likely, your C++ dynamic vector already has more than just a few bytes allocated to it. Computers have a lot of RAM today. The vector class also supports what you asked (vector of vectors of ints) afaik.

Answer (score 1):

The std::pmr namespace contains a couple of useful tools, including allocators that allocate from an existing buffer, so that you don't have to write your own. You can use std::pmr::vector together with such an allocator to avoid syscalls.
Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory_resource>

int main(int, char**)
{
    char buffer[512];
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource resource(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::vector<int> > v(&resource);
    // The resource will be passed to the inner vectors.
    // no memory is allocated if the buffer is sufficient
    v.resize(5);
    for (auto&& i : v)
        i.resize(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Issue with that is that monotonic_buffer_resource doesn't deallocate memory as do_deallocate does nothing. AFAIK pmr offers no memory resource with preallocated space other than monotonic. One would have to write their own memory resource class.

Comment: monotonic_buffer_resource::do_deallocate does indeed nothing, so allocated and freed memory of "buffer" in the example above won't become available again until the main function terminates. If this is a problem, you could chain memory resources: E.g. you could use an unsynchronized_pool_resource that is constructed with a monotonic_buffer_resource as upstream resource.

Depending on the implementation, still some deallocated memory may become unavailable if unsynchronized_pool_resource::do_deallocate calls upstream's deallocate(). It is unspecified if it does.